# Get-AzureADUser reference of all available fields

Tags: powershell, azure-activedirectory

For the Azure AD cmdlet, [Get-AzureADUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/AzureAD/Get-AzureADUser?view=azureadps-2.0), can someone point me to a reference of all possible fields?

The scenario...

I wanted to export users, including their manager. Here is the only way I found to do this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48778134

but I wanted to also flesh out first name, last name and other fields, and I couldn't guess correctly (e.g. firstname, userfirstname). I had to search for a lucky find: givenname and surname, but what are the others??

I would have thought that the Microsoft reference page for [Get-AzureADUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/AzureAD/Get-AzureADUser?view=azureadps-2.0) would at least have a link to a reference of the returned object, including its properties, but I can't find such a thing. I also typed *user* into the search on the left, since it is the object returned--nothing.

Comment: I was able to find documentation on [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/Set-AzureADUser?view=azureadps-2.0) without much fanfare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see a list of all the attributes on an Azure AD user object:

```
Get-AzureADUser -Top 1 | gm -MemberType Properties
```

To see an Azure user and all their properties:

```
Get-AzureADUser -Top 1 | Format-List
```

To see an Azure user and all its properties, including Manager, and export to csv:

```
Get-AzureADUser -Top 1 | 
  Select-Object *,@{label="Manager";expression={(Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $_.ObjectID).displayname}} | 
  Export-Csv \\path\to\file.csv
```